# Heroku local app testing missing System.out in console

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I have tried searching in a ton of places for why this might be happening, but I can not for the life of me figure it out.  There are calls to System.out.printf(...); that are simply missing from the terminal when main is executed.  The other weirdness is that it is not the same ones each time.  I can run the app two consecutive times, without code change or re-build, and the output is missing different System.out calls.

This is a Maven Build.  I have three objects.  The class that contains main, a User object, and a DB access object.

The main object is using a connection to build and send email.  The Db object is using a connection to access a psql local DB.

Here is a few snippets of code that are showing issue.

```
public static List<User_Search_Profile> getAllTable(String tableName, PrintStream out){
    List<User_Search_Profile> users = new ArrayList<User_Search_Profile>();
    Connection connection = Database_Access.establishConnection();
    try{                        
        ResultSet resultTable = Database_Access.generateResultSet("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, connection);
        ResultSetMetaData resultTableMetaData = resultTable.getMetaData();
        ResultSet abvTable = Database_Access.generateResultSet("SELECT * FROM CLSEARCHTABLE", connection);
        connection.close();

        int columns = resultTableMetaData.getColumnCount();
        out.printf("Columns: " + columns + "%n");

        String [] labels = new String[columns];                     
        for(int i = 1; i <= columns; i++){
            labels[i-1] = resultTableMetaData.getColumnLabel(i).toString();
            out.printf("Label: " + labels[i-1] + "%n");

        }

        Map<String, String> dbVals = new HashMap<String, String>();

        resultTable.first();                
        while(!resultTable.isAfterLast()){

            for(String s: labels){
                dbVals.put(s, resultTable.getString(s));
            }               
            User_Search_Profile user = new User_Search_Profile(dbVals.get("region"), dbVals.get("category"),
                    dbVals.get("name"), dbVals.get("email"), dbVals.get("search"), dbVals.get("lasthash"));                 
            users.add(user);                    
            resultTable.next();


        }           
        resultTable.close();  


        abvTable.first();
        for(User_Search_Profile user: users){                   

            while(!abvTable.isAfterLast()){
                if(abvTable.getString(1) == user.getCategory()){
                    user.setCategoryAbv(abvTable.getString(2));
                }
                if(abvTable.getString(1) == user.getRegion()){
                    user.setRegionAbv(abvTable.getString(2));
                }
                abvTable.next();

            }   
            user.printUser(out); //Calls the user object print
        }

    }
```

And the User Objects part:

```
    public void printUser(PrintStream out){
    out.printf("--User--%n%n");
    out.printf("Name: " + name + "%n");
    out.printf("Email: " + email + "%n");
    out.printf("Reg: " + region + "%n");
    out.printf("Abv: " + regionAbv + "%n");
    out.printf("Cat: " + category + "%n");
    out.printf("Abv: " + categoryAbv + "%n");
    out.printf("Search: " + searchString + "%n");
    out.printf("Hash: " + lastHash + "%n");
    //out.flush();

}
```

And here is the out put for consecutive runs:

```
james ~/heroku/java-getting-started $ heroku local worker
forego  | starting worker.1 on port 5100
worker.1 | Columns: 6
worker.1 | Label: region
worker.1 | Label: category
worker.1 | Label: name
worker.1 | Label: email
worker.1 | Label: search
worker.1 | Label: lasthash
worker.1 | --User--
worker.1 | 
worker.1 | Name: James
worker.1 | Email: ************
worker.1 | Reg: Clackamas County
worker.1 | Abv: null
worker.1 | Cat: Jobs
worker.1 | Abv: null
worker.1 | Search: Web Developer
worker.1 | Hash: ccdd352048003f7feae23004c5df2caa
james ~/heroku/java-getting-started $ heroku local worker
forego  | starting worker.1 on port 5100
worker.1 | Columns: 6
worker.1 | Label: region
worker.1 | Label: category
worker.1 | Label: name
worker.1 | Label: email
worker.1 | Label: search
worker.1 | Label: lasthash
worker.1 | --User--
worker.1 | 
worker.1 | Name: James
worker.1 | Email: **********
james ~/heroku/java-getting-started $ heroku local worker
forego  | starting worker.1 on port 5100
worker.1 | Columns: 6
worker.1 | Label: region
worker.1 | Label: category
worker.1 | Label: name
worker.1 | Label: search
worker.1 | Label: lasthash
worker.1 | --User--
worker.1 | 
worker.1 | Name: James
worker.1 | Email: ***********   // not encrypted just personal
worker.1 | 
worker.1 | Abv: null
worker.1 | Cat: Jobs
james ~/heroku/java-getting-started $
```

I am super confounded.  It seems there is a buffer issue, or the output is going elsewhere, but damned if I know where.  Any help would be appreciated since debugging is near impossible where I cant verify output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the underlying [forego](https://github.com/ddollar/forego) tool, which `heroku local` uses to run your process.

I think the toolbelt still installs `foreman`, so you could try running `foreman start worker` instead.

In the end, you could always just run the Procfile command manually, but you'll need to set up your env vars manually too.

Comment: Thank you.  I was not sure if it was that or not.  After an install of foreman, I get consistent output!  :)  Now I can solve 'MY' issues.